# capturing group in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am exploring capturing groups in Regex and I am getting confused about lack of documentation on it. For ex, can anyone tell me difference between two regex:

```
/(?:madhur)?/
```

and

```
/(madhur)?/
```

As per me, ? in second suggests matching `madhur` zero or once in the string.

How is the first different from second ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The first one won't store the capturing group, e.g. `$1` will be empty. The `?:` prefix makes it a *non capturing group*. This is usually done for better performance and un-cluttering of back references.

In the second example, the characters in the capturing group will be stored in the backreference `$1`.

[Further Reading](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Why would you want to use non capturing grouping? Like wouldn't the parentheses be redundant in that case?

In other words, what is different between: /(?:madhur)?/ and /madhur?/

Comment: the reason is to apply a condition to whole text. and no those two aren't the same. 1st is madhur is optional in 2nd only r is optional.

Comment: @alex... why capture group results in different outcomes when used in match or split. Ex:, `" , ".match(/(\s+)?,(\s+)?/)` results in **[","," "," "]** while `" , ".match(/(\s+)?,(\s+)?/g)` or `" , ".match(/[\s+]?,[\s+]?/)` results in **[","]**. Can you explain why

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Adding `g` changes how matches are returned with `match()` if you have capturing groups.

Comment: i know i just learned...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577704/why-capturing-group-results-in-double-matches-regex

Answer (score 20):

Here's the most obvious example:

```
"madhur".replace(/(madhur)?/, "$1 ahuja");   // returns "madhur ahuja"
"madhur".replace(/(?:madhur)?/, "$1 ahuja"); // returns "$1 ahuja"
```

Backreferences are stored in order such that the first match can be recalled with `$1`, the second with `$2`, etc. If you capture a match (i.e. `(...)` instead of `(?:...)`), you can use these, and if you don't then there's nothing special. As another example, consider the following:

```
/(mad)hur/.exec("madhur");   // returns an array ["madhur", "mad"]
/(?:mad)hur/.exec("madhur"); // returns an array ["madhur"]
```

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't affect the matching at all.

It tells the regex engine

- not to store the group contents for use (as $1, $2, ...) by the `replace()` method
- not to return it in the return array of the `exec()` method and
- not to count it as a backreference (\1, \2, etc.)

Comment: One minor nit:  It will change the matching in some cases.  E.g. in `/(foo)\1/` will match `"foofoo"`, but `/(?:foo)\1/` will not.   The `\1` is interpreted as a back-reference in the first, and as an octal escape sequence in the second.

Comment: why these two are different `" , ".match(/(\s+)?,(\s+)?/)` and `" , ".match(/[\s+]?,[\s+]?/)` they output different arrays.

Comment: One uses a group that says "one or more whitespaces or none at all" and the other one uses a character class that says "a whitespace or a plus or nothing at all".