# regular expressions difference between ((?:[^\"])*) and ([^\"]*)

Tags: javascript, regex

what is the difference between this regular expressions are the replaceable?

```
((?:[^\"])*)


([^\"]*)
```

background to this question:

The javascript WYSIWYG editor (tinymce) fails to parse my html code
in Firefox (23.0.1 and 25.0a2) but works in in Chrome.

I found the regular expression to blame:

```
attrRegExp = /([\w:\-]+)(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:\"((?:[^\"])*)\")|(?:\'((?:[^\'])*)\')|([^>\s]+)))?/g;
```

which I modified, replacing

```
((?:[^\"])*)
```

with

```
([^\"]*)
```

and

```
((?:[^\'])*)
```

with

```
([^\']*)
```

the resulting regular expression is working in both browsers for my test case

```
attrRegExp = /([\w:\-]+)(?:\s*=\s*(?:(?:\"([^\"]*)\")|(?:\'([^\']*)\')|([^>\s]+)))?/g
```

can someone put some light on that?

my test data that only works with the modified regular expression is a big image >700 kb like:

```
var testdata = '<img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA...5PmDk4FOGOHy6S3JW120W1uCJ5M0PBa54edOFAc8ePX/2Q==">'
```

doing something like that to test:

```
testdata.match(attrRegExp);
```

especially when the test data is big the unmodified regex is likely to fail in firefox.

You can find the [jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/JKb2A/1/):

Comment: Nice observation. Maybe a Firefox/Gecko bug?

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37: That won't help OP at all, since he is not to blame for the code of TinyMCE (I suppose)

Comment: There should be no difference. Do you experience any?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to escape quotes in a regex. Do you see any difference when using `"` instead of `\"` (and `'` instead of `\'`)?

Comment: you are right there is no difference

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=838588

Comment: The only difference is that the former doesn't capture groups, the latter does.  That is, you can use \num back references in the latter.

Comment: @Sumurai8, g13n: No, both regexes do capture around the repetition. Only at the first one the repeated character class is enclosed in a non-capturing group, while it is not in the second

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no difference in the result. So you should be fine.

However, there might be a big difference in how RegExp engines will process these two expressions, and in the case of Firefox/Safari you just proved there actually is ;)

Firefox makes use of WebKit/JavaScriptCore YARR.
YARR imposes an arbitrary, [artificial limit](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/yarr/Yarr.h?rev=112564#L50), which hits in the non-capturing group variant

```
// The below limit restricts the number of "recursive" match calls in order to
// avoid spending exponential time on complex regular expressions.
static const unsigned matchLimit = 1000000;
```

As such Safari is affected as well.

See the relevant [Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25071) and relevant [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=838588) and the [nice test case](https://bug838588.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=720221) comparing different expression types somebody put together.