# Flatten a json datastructure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a json response coming from a service that's a bit of a pain to work with. How can I go about flattening this structure a bit so that  `"not_restricted":{"doc_count": 976465}` is changed to `"not_restricted":976465`? I'd perfer a function that can detect this kind of a structure in all types of json docs and modify the result.

This is a the general structure of the json:

```
{
    "took": 159,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 6,
        "successful": 6,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 4909332,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "index_types": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "client",
                    "doc_count": 1958205,
                    "not_restricted": {
                        "doc_count": 976465
                    },
                    "restricted": {
                        "doc_count": 981740
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ultimateparent",
                    "doc_count": 1616164,
                    "not_restricted": {
                        "doc_count": 741059
                    },
                    "restricted": {
                        "doc_count": 875105
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "facility",
                    "doc_count": 1334963,
                    "not_restricted": {
                        "doc_count": 914090
                    },
                    "restricted": {
                        "doc_count": 420872
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have actual JSON or do you already have an object?

Comment: no it's actually json. Its json response from a service

Comment: @HorseVoice you might want to checkout https://lodash.com/docs#flatten and https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDeep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can very easily do this by using the [`reviver` parameter of `JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which allows you to filter every object in the JSON:

```
var res = JSON.parse(json, function(k, o) {
    if (Object(o) !== o) return o; // primitive values
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    if (keys.length == 1 && keys[0] == "doc_count")
        return o.doc_count;
    else
        return o;
});
```

You can also test `k` to include `"restricted"` or so if you want to make sure that `doc_count` singletons are only replaced in such properties.

Comment: Bergi -I'm not sure what this does as I'm new to javascript, but does this modify the existing doc? Lets say `json` argument is the response doc. Does it just modify it? or is this just returning the aggs portion of it?

Comment: No, it returns a parsed version (object) of the `json` string in which each `{"doc_count":…}` object is replaced by the `…` only. Btw, you cannot "modify" strings in JS, they're immutable. If you need to get JSON back, you can use `JSON.stringify(res, null, 4)`; and if you want you can overwrite the `json` variable with it.

Comment: So it returns the entire doc? just with the slight modification of doc_count?

Comment: Yes, it returns an object for the complete JSON without the doc_count objects. Just try it out and inspect the result in your console :-)

Comment: How would I make this as a predefined method? I'm using extjs framework and it is not understanding this functional way of doing this. How can I make it so that I define a specific method that does just this, and then invoke it where I need it in the code, by passing in the response and this method returns the response? Also I don't think JSON.parse is working in my IE 8 old enterprise .

Comment: Yes, you should just be able to wrap it in a function that takes `json` as a parameter and returns `res`. Not sure how your extjs code looks like and how to integrate it there, can you add that to your question? Yes, `JSON.parse` needs to be shimmed for IE8 support, but that should not be a problem.

Comment: Okay this does not seem to work. It is returning an empty string. There are other fields on the json doc that are perhaps getting in the way. But this is a very specific alteration I need to make regarding `restricted` and `unrestricted` I updated the json in my question for the completeness of the doc structure. I need the entire doc back as is but with the specif modification.

Comment: Oops, sorry for not testing (and forgetting what parameters the reviver takes :-/). Fixed snippet, tested against question, updated answer.

Comment: That's why you are awesome! Thank you it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LoDash](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) to make your life easier.  Include it, and then you can use _.each

```
_.each(data.aggregations.index_types.buckets, function(n){
  n.not_restricted = n.not_restricted.doc_count;
  n.restricted = n.restricted.doc_count;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go thru the object and flatten all 1 property objects, you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.aggregations["index_types"].buckets.length; i++) {
    var obj = data.aggregations["index_types"].buckets[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 1) {
            //1 property object!
            obj[key] = obj[key][Object.keys(obj[key])[0]];
        } 
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jkm1vmbm/

Comment: It's actually a json string. Not really an object. Would It work the same way? sorry I'm new to javascript

Comment: @HorseVoice -- Use `JSON.parse(str)` to convert it to an object - it won't work the same if it's just a string.

Comment: then I'd have to convert that back to a string for processing. for that I can just do String(jsonDoc) right?

Comment: @HorseVoice -- `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: This only returns the modified object and forgets the rest of the json. This does not work for me. I need the entire doc back with the flattened doc_count garbage inside restricted and unrestricted

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that the JSON are actually strings, if all you need is that specific replacement:

```
Replacing `{"doc_count": NUMBER}` with that `NUMBER`
```

What you can do is just use a regex to replace what you want:

```
s.replace(/({"doc_count":([0-9]+)})/g, '$2')
```

Which works like:

```
(                   // start capturing group 1
{\"doc_count\":     // match the string {\"doc_count\":
    (               // start capturing group 2
    [0-9]+          // match one or more digits
    )               // close capturing group 2
}                   // add the rest of the string (a closing bracket)
```

Then you can use `$2` in your `replace()` to extract only the number from the [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 2.

```js
var json = {
  "aggregations": {
    "index_types": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [{
        "key": "client",
        "doc_count": 1958205,
        "not_restricted": {
          "doc_count": 976465
        },
        "restricted": {
          "doc_count": 981740
        }
      }, {
        "key": "ultimateparent",
        "doc_count": 1616164,
        "not_restricted": {
          "doc_count": 741059
        },
        "restricted": {
          "doc_count": 875105
        }
      }, {
        "key": "facility",
        "doc_count": 1334963,
        "not_restricted": {
          "doc_count": 914090
        },
        "restricted": {
          "doc_count": 420872
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};

var s = JSON.stringify(json);
// replace all instances of {doc_count: NUMBER} with that NUMBER
console.log(s.replace(/({"doc_count":([0-9]+)})/g, '$2'));
```

I also noticed that you have properties `doc_count` outside of `restricted` and `non_restricted`. If you only want to replace the ones within a property `restricted` or `non_restricted`, You can use this regex:

```
("((?:not_)?restricted"):{"doc_count":([0-9]+)})
```

That added part at the beginning basically means "starts with 'restricted' with an optional 'not_' before it"

It's used like:

```
s.replace(/("((?:not_)?restricted"):{"doc_count":([0-9]+)})/g, '"$2:$3')
```

```js
var json = {
  "aggregations": {
    "index_types": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [{
        "key": "client",
        "doc_count": 1958205,
        "not_restricted": {
          "doc_count": 976465
        },
        "restricted": {
          "doc_count": 981740
        }
      }, {
        "key": "ultimateparent",
        "doc_count": 1616164,
        "not_restricted": {
          "doc_count": 741059
        },
        "restricted": {
          "doc_count": 875105
        }
      }, {
        "key": "facility",
        "doc_count": 1334963,
        "not_restricted": {
          "doc_count": 914090
        },
        "restricted": {
          "doc_count": 420872
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};

var s = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(s.replace(/("((?:not_)?restricted"):{"doc_count":([0-9]+)})/g, '"$2:$3'));
```

NOTE: using `?:` for the `(?:not_)` makes the part in parenthesis a **non-capturing** group so it doesn't get counted in the capturing groups. The term "restricted" with the optional "not_" before it is now contained in group 2 and the number value is in group 3. We also need to prepend a `"` and combine the two groups with a `:`.

Comment: It is a [regex capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6419003/3928341). Essentially, you can capture portions (or groups) of the matches.

Comment: @HorseVoice I added much more explanation, hopefully that helps

Comment: Yea, all the other structure MUST be same. Only restricted and unrestricted. There are other fields on the doc and lists etc, with nested doc_counts that I DONT want to mess with at all. This is very specific. How do I use this? `("(?:not_)?restricted":{"doc_count":([0-9]+)})`

Comment: The same way you would use the other regex. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay, this did not do anything. The response was unmodified. And I still see doc_count inside of restricted and not_restricted

Comment: @HorseVoice I found a bug, the regex I had was replacing the whole match with the number. Now I added a fix to also include the "restricted"/"not_restricted" portion and I added code snippet to demonstrate.

Comment: @HorseVoice how was the response unmodified? Are you sure you are using it right? Using `.replace` creates a new string so you should use it like `var myNewJson = myOldJson.replace(...)`

Comment: yes I'm doing it like that. I love this answer but since it didn't work I couldn't accept it.

Comment: @HorseVoice You must not be using it correctly because it works in the code snippet I provided. If you run the script it will alert the JSON with the values altered as specified.