# Regex behaving weird when finding floating point strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

So doing this (in python 3.7.3):

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> s = '7.95 + 10 pieces'
>>> findall(r'(\d*\.)?\d+', s)
['7.', '']   # Expected return: ['7.95', '10']
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't find all the floats inside? Is this possibly some python quirk about capturing groups?

My logic behind the regex:
`(\d*\.)?` matches either 1 or none of any number of digits, followed by a period.
`\d+` then maches any number of digits, so this regex should match any of `11.11, 11, .11` and so on. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed correctly, this has to do with capturing groups. According to the documentation for [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups

Therefore, you need to make all your groups `()` [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex) using the `(?:)` specifier. If there are no captured groups, it will return the entire match:

```
>>> pattern = r'(?:\d*\.)?\d+'

>>> findall(pattern, s)
['7.95', '10']
```

Comment: What does it mean to make a group non-capturing?

Comment: @HHC this is explained very well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418985/capturing-group-in-regex

Comment: Hhm, so what does it mean when it returns ```['7.', '']```? How is ```'7.'``` a group?

Comment: In your original regex, the group was `(\d*\.)`. Which matches `7.` in `7.95` and the empty string in `10`. A group is specified by a set of parenthesis `()`

Comment: Also, if you're still there, do you think this is a good regex for retrieving simple floats from strings? Or could it be simpler?

Comment: Well for one, it doesn't handle negative numbers. But as long as it satisfies your need, yes it seems reasonable