# Count max consecutive RE groups in a string

Tags: python, regex

How can I count the max amount of consecutive string groups in a string?

```
import re

s = "HELLOasdHELLOasdHELLOHELLOHELLOasdHELLOHELLO"

# Give me the max amount of consecutive HELLO groups ---> wich is 3
# There's a group of 3 and a group of 2, but 3 is the max.

count = re.findall("(HELLO)+", s)        # count is: ['HELLO', 'HELLO', 'HELLO', 'HELLO']
count = len(count)
print(count)
```

Output is:

> 4

Which is totally wrong. The max amount of consecutive HELLO is 3.

I think I'm using the wrong RE and I have no clue how to count those repetitions in order to find the max.

And I can't understand why the output is 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the entire string of consecutive `HELLO`s in your match; then you can work out the number of `HELLO`s by dividing the length of the match string by 5 (the length of `HELLO`). Using a list comprehension:

```
import re

s = "HELLOasdHELLOasdHELLOHELLOHELLOasdHELLOHELLO"

print(max([len(x) // 5 for x in re.findall(r'((?:HELLO)+)', s)]))
```

Output

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this question: [Regex behaving weird when finding floating point strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745069/regex-behaving-weird-when-finding-floating-point-strings/59745087#59745087)

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, [`re.findall` will] return a list of groups

Therefore you want a non-capturing group instead. Let's work through with the sample string and pattern:

```py
s = 'HELLOasdHELLOasdHELLOHELLOHELLOasdHELLOHELLO'
p = 'HELLO'
```

To find all occurrences of consecutive repetitions of the pattern, we just need to modify your regex slight to use a non-capturing group:

```py
>>> matches = re.findall(f'(?:{p})+', s)
>>> matches
['HELLO', 'HELLO', 'HELLOHELLOHELLO', 'HELLOHELLO']
```

Now we just need to find the longest string and divide its length by the length of the pattern:

```py
>> max(map(len, matches)) // len(p)
3
```

Comment: sorry, the original post allowed two different interpretations. not sure which one is correct.

Comment: Thank you!

matches = re.findall('(?:{p})+', s)

I'd put the f for format before the first ' to ensure that python knows that it has to replace p.

That way it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change to another solution that is easier to understand than looking for short code.

```
s = "HELLOasdHELLOasdHELLOHELLOHELLOasdHELLOHELLO"

word_search = "HELLO"


def find_char(str_var: str, word_search: str) -> int:
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        char = word_search * i
        if str_var.find(char) != - 1:
            count = i
    return count


find = find_char(s)
print(find) # 3
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
Update:
Actually it can work with one line of code without requiring additional modules:

```
 c = max([i for i in range(len(s)) if s.find('HELLO' * i) != -1])
```

- There are many cases where people use Regular Expressions to cool and reject simpler solutions to work.
- Back to the topic of the topic owner. **He doesn't understand why the output = 4.**
- Because re.findall () will return a list of elements that it finds, here, it finds 4 elements. 
  And len (list) will return the total number of elements in a list -> **`output = 4.`**
- with the regex of the above answers, it also found 4 elements and when assembled into the top code, len(list) = 4.
- We need to explain that len​​(list) is not right.
- The problem is in the form of `find max(x) if x * 'HELLO' in s`.
- Regex is a powerful and useful tool! but we don't always use it.

Comment: I liked this solution without using regex. It is clear indeed. I didn't thought about using the find method. Thank you!